# Customization of Facebook style Statues module

Tags: social-network

I am using Drupal 7 with [Facebook-style Statues](http://drupal.org/project/facebook_status) module.

While writing the status I would like to load the URL when user paste any URL, just like facebook.

Is there any way to customize this module or do i have to build entire new module.

Comment: you supposed to be use Statuses module for D7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [Facebook-style Micropublisher](http://drupal.org/project/fbsmp) this allows you to have a image present if the URL your connecting to allows it.